# High pitched sound from speakers when monitor off

Tags: speakers

I have self powered computer speakers that work fine when the monitor is on. However, the second the monitor is off, whether it times out or manually turned off, they emit a high frequency sound. Almost like whining. Not a static or crackling but a whine. The instant the screen comes back on, they go quiet.

Comment: Does that only happen, when the monitor goes into standby or completely disconnected from power grid? Have you tried using another audio cable? Have you tried other devices like audio output from the pc, smartphone or another monitor?

Comment: It wasn't the audio signal, it was the power. Turning off the monitor was somehow disconnecting that ground. The speakers were powered from a USB port on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. The speakers were getting power from USB plugged into a USB port on the monitor. So when the monitor was turned off, even though power was still supplied, the ground was somehow gone. So there was no ground and that's what was making that sound, the amp without ground. I plugged the USB cable that powers the speakers into another power supply and so the ground and power remain regardless of the monitor state.